# Divide the leaderboard into pages discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I would like my leaderboard to split into multiple pages depending on how many users there are.
For example, if there are 5 users, only one page remains, instead if there are 23 users it divides them into 3 pages of which the first 2 show 10 users while the last shows the last 3 users left.
I've tried many ways and I've gotten to this point where I don't really know what to do. Can you solve?
Any method is accepted as long as it works.

```py
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT users.user_level, users.user_xp, users.client_id\nFROM users\nORDER BY users.user_level DESC , users.user_xp DESC")
    leaderboard = cursor.fetchall()
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Leaderboard del {ctx.guild.name}",
        colour=0x003399
    )
    for i, pos in enumerate(leaderboard, start=1):
        lvl, xp, member_id = pos
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT xp_level FROM levels WHERE level = {lvl+1}")
        xp_level = cursor.fetchall()
        xp_level = xp_level[0][0]
        member = await client.fetch_user(member_id)
        sorted_users = ## get all the members and sort them...
        pages = grouper(sorted_users, 10)
        print(pages)
        embed.add_field(
            name=f"{i}. {member.display_name}",
            value=f"Livello attuale: {lvl}\n\t\tXP: {xp}/{xp_level}\n",
            inline=False
        )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paginate the embeds with reactions:

```
import asyncio

@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT user_level, user_xp, client_id FROM users ORDER BY user_level DESC, user_xp DESC")
    users = cursor.fetchall()
    pages = []
    page_count = -(-len(users)//10)) #will return 3 if users' length is 23
    for i in range(page_count):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = f"Leaderboard del {ctx.guild.name}",
            colour = 0x003399
        )
        embed.set_footer(
            text = f"Page {i + 1}/{page_count}"
        )
        for rank, data in enumerate(users[i * 10:i * 10 + 10], start=i * 10 + 1):
            level = data[0]
            xp = data[1]
            user = await client.fetch_user(data[2])
    
            embed.add_field(
                name = f"#{rank} {user}",
                value = f"Level: {level}\nExperience: {xp}"
                inline = False
            )
        pages.append(embed)

    index = 0
    message = await ctx.send(embed=pages[0])
    emojis = ["◀️", "⏹", "▶️"]
    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    while not client.is_closed():
        try:
            react, user = await client.wait_for(
                "reaction_add",
                timeout = 60.0,
                check = lambda r, u: r.emoji in emojis and u.id == ctx.author.id and r.message.id == message.id
            )
            if react.emoji == emojis[0] and index > 0:
                index -= 1
            elif react.emoji == emojis[1]:
                await message.delete()
                break
            elif react.emoji == emojis[2] and index < len(pages) - 1:
                index += 1

            await message.edit(embed=pages[index])
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()
            break
```

Comment: This script is very good, that's what I needed but it has a pretty big problem. I tried to order 11 users but on the second page it gives me the wrong positions. How can this be solved? ([image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/840746401885716520/unknown.png))

Comment: as you can see from the image the 10th became 19th on the second page

Comment: I edited the enumerate line. Can you try it again?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, I added `print(index, pages)` to see the variables and it only changed the index. [Here the image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/840888438890299442/unknown.png). [Here is my database which confirms that there are 15 users](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/840889549218775080/unknown.png)

Comment: I ran the code on my bot with a fake database and it worked perfectly. I don't know why you getting this error.

Comment: when I want to see the second page it doesn't give me any update of the embed and it still marks the first page. It does not give me any error in the console and besides now there are more users in the database since I test the bot on my server. The pages are updated but the embeds are only the first 10.
[image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/840898379944951848/unknown.png)

Comment: another [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/638016878589116416/840899726223081522/unknown.png) (I forgot to add it). Here despite I press the reaction it does not give me any updates.

Comment: No ok in the end it's gone. In the code you entered there were two syntax errors that it did not go. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Per Discord's documentation on embed limits, found [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits), you can have up to 25 field objects and the embed should not exceed over 6000 characters maximum.

With this information in mind, you could create a function that keeps track of the character count and field count. Once one of these limits is exceeded, a separate "page" should be created to still keep the embed under these limits.

You will need to store the current state of the message and have a [reaction_add event listener](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add). In your reaction_add event listener, you will need to check the message again and check what page is it at and [edit the message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit) to have the new embed.

I hope this helps. I'll check the comments and help you if you get stuck!

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the delay in answering by now I thought there was no one to help me. I don't know how I could do this function is it possible to have some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Idk if that's what you mean but try this:

```py
import math


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    users = [
        "user1",
        "user2",
        "user3",
        "user4",
        "user5",
        "user6",
        "user7",
        "user8",
        "user9",
        "user10",
        "user11",
        "user12",
        "user13",
        "user14",
        "user15",
        "user16",
        "user17",
        "user18",
        "user19",
        "user20",
        "user21",
        "user22",
        "user23",
    ]
    pages = {}
    numOfPages = math.ceil(len(users) / 10)
    j = 0
    for i in range(numOfPages):
        pages[f"page{i}"] = discord.Embed(title=f"Page {i+1}")
        displayUsers = ""
        while j < 10 + i * 10:
            try:
                displayUsers += users[j] + "\n"
            except:
                break
            j += 1
        pages[f"page{i}"].add_field(name="Users:", value=displayUsers)
        await ctx.send(embed=pages[f"page{i}"])
```

It creates `discord.Embed` objects accordingly to user count with the for loop and then sends them after each other.

Comment: I hadn't thought about using math. For the rest the division is there and what was needed but I use the databases and I am forced to import them from there. Plus when you run the command it gives me all the pages without the ability to manage the pages (with reactions or numbers). Unfortunately it is not enough.